# Is it possible to call Text Selection Toolbar when click on a menu item on Action Bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, textselection

I need my app can show text selection toolbar after I click on a menu bar. I mean when I choose an item on menu bar may be like this [Menu Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pQ12.png), after that my device will appear Text Selection Toolbar like this
[Text Selection Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap0gx.png)

Is it possible to do that? Please help me. Thank you.
This is my code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //add(groupId, itemId, order, name)
    menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Copy Text");
    menu.add(1, 2, 2, "Exit");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml

        case 1:
            //Show text selection toolbar

        case 2:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        default:
            break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```